# using ostream as function argument

Tags: c++, class, ostream

I have a basic problem with understanding what ostream is exactly. I know that it's a base class for the output stream, but I can't quite gasp when to use it and why to use it instead of just saying std::cout. 
So here I have this example where I have to create a new class named stack with a pop() function (just as in the class already provided by C++).

Here list_node is a struct which consists of two elements: the key (which is an integer) and an interator which points to the next integer.

Definition of list_node (already given):

```
struct list_node {
int key;
list_node∗ next;
// constructor
list_node (int k, list_node∗ n)
: key (k), next (n) {}
};
```

and here is the definition of the class (already given as well):

```
class stack {
public:
void push (int value) {...}
...
private:
list_node∗ top_node;
};
```

and here's the part with which I'm having trouble with:

```
void print (std::ostream& o) const
{
const list_node* p = top_node;
while (p != 0) {
o << p->key << " "; // 1 5 6
p = p->next;
}
}
```

I don't understand why they are using ostream& o as function argument. Couldn't they've just taken the top_node as argument and used as well .next function on it (.next reads the next list_node) and then they could've just printed it with the std::cout function. Why is it better to do it the way they did?

Comment: First off, `std::ostream` is certainly **not** another name for `std::cout`. Former is a base class, second is an object of unspecified type. Second of all, it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Is this method defined inside the stack? Is `top_node` a member of the stack class? It is really unclear what you’re asking; it looks like there’s a lot of missing context.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @SergeyA, I edited it. I hope that it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it better to do it the way they did?

I am not sure of your question, and not sure it is a better way.

Perhaps the intent was for flexibility.  Here is an example from my app library:

---

When I declare a data attribute as an ostream

```
class T431_t
{
   // ...
   std::ostream*      m_so; 
   // ...
```

I can trivially use that attribute to deliver a report to 'where-m_so-points'.  In this app, there are several examples of *mso << ... being used.  Here is the primary example.

```
inline void reportProgress()
{
    // ...
   *m_so << "  m_blk = " << m_blk
         << "  m_N = 0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::setw(16) << m_N
         << "  " << std::dec << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(3) << durationSec
         << "."  << std::dec << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << durationMSec
         << " sec  (" << std::dec << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(14)
         << digiComma(m_N) << ")" << std::endl;
   // ...
}
```

Note that in the class constructor (ctor), there is a default assignment for m_so to std::cout.

```
T431_t(uint64_t maxDuration = MaxSingleCoreMS) :
      // ..
      m_so   (&std::cout), // ctor init - default
      // ..
 {
    // ...
```

---

When the user selects the dual-thread processing option, which is a command line option to perform the app in about 1/2 the time by using both processors of my desktop, the reports can become hard to read if I allow the two independent output streams to intertwine (on the user screen).  Thus, in the object instance being run by thread 2, m_so is set some something different.

The following data attribute captures and holds thread 2 output for later streaming to std::cout.

```
std::stringstream  m_ssMagic; // dual threads use separate out streams
```

Thread 2 is launched and the thread sets it's private m_so:

```
void exec2b ()  //  thread 2 entry
{
    m_now = Clock_t::now();

    m_so = &m_ssMagic; // m_so points to m_ssMagic 

    // ...

    m_ssMagic << "   execDuration =  " << m_ssDuration.str() 
              << " (b)  " << std::endl;
} // exec2b (void)
```

---

While thread 1 uses std::cout, and thread 2 uses m_ssMagic, 'main' (thread 0) simply waits for the joins.

The join's coordinate the thread completion, typically about the same time. Main (thread 0) then cout's the m_ssMagic contents.

```
//...
// main thread context:
case 2: // one parameter: 2 threads each runs 1/2 of tests
{  // use two new instances
    T431_t  t431a(MaxDualCoreMS); // lower test sequence
    T431_t  t431b(MaxDualCoreMS); // upper test sequence

    // 2 additional threads started here
    std::thread tA (&T431_t::exec2a, &t431a);
    std::thread tB (&T431_t::exec2b, &t431b);

    // 2 join's - thread main (0) waits for each to complete
    tA.join();
    tB.join();

    // tA outputs directly to std::cout
    // tB captured output to T431_t::m_ssMagic. 

    // both thread 1 and 2 have completed, so ok to:
    std::cout << t431b.ssMagicShow() << std::endl;

    retVal = 0;
} break;
```

To be complete, here is

```
std::string ssMagicShow() { return (m_ssMagic.str()); }
```

---

Summary

I wrote the single thread application first.  After getting that working, I searched for a 'simple' way to make use of the second core on my desktop.

As part of my first refactor, I a) added "std::ostream m_so" initialized to &std::cout, and b) found all uses of std::cout.  Most of these I simply replaced with "*m_so".  I then c) confirmed that I had not broken the single thread solution.  Quite easy, and worked the first try.

Subsequent effort implemented the command line 'dual-thread' option.

I think this approach will apply to my next desktop, when budget allows.

---

And from an OOP standpoint, this effort works because std::ostream is in the class hierarchy of both std::cout and std::stringstream.  Thus

```
 "std::cout is-a std::ostream",
```

and

```
"std::stringstream is-a std::ostream".
```

So m_so can point to instance of either derived class, and provide virtual method 'ostream-access' to either destination.